# In tissue tools, I do not have the option to convert to dual mesh

Tags: mesh, add-on, tools

I am trying to follow a tutorial that uses the tissue tools add on. In their tutorial, they have different tabs and options than me. Anyone know where the option went that lets you convert to dual mesh?[image: this is the image from the tutorial]

[image: and here is all that I am seeing]

edit: manually downloaded and installed tissue v 3.5, and it fixed the issue

Comment: Are you in the right mode? These menus change when you change from Object to Edit

Comment: yeah, it's the same menu in both object and edit mode

Comment: Are you using the latest release version (3.50)? You can download it [here](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/releases/tag/v0-3-50). That does have the Dual Mesh entry (under Generate) and also 'Convert to Dual Mesh' under the 'Other' section menu on the sidebar.

Comment: I wasn't, I tried what you said and it worked. The update mentioned something about fixing this issue, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!